# upload and import csv file into multiple table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I would like to create and upload page in php and import the uploaded csv file data into multiple tables. tried searching here but looks like can't find any which is importing from a csv to multiple table. any help here is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple tables: Is all the data going into multiple tables, or is some data going into one table, other data going into another etc?

Comment: yes, i meant data from some rows goes into one table, other goes into another table.

Comment: this is helpful but looks like i wont be able to use it for my project as the csv should be giving the user a dropdown selection taken from the db. so i have to use another way for this.

Comment: If you are looking at doing this using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, you can refer to this article here, which talks about splitting a CSV file into multiple tables: https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/05/splitting-csv-file-into-multiple-mysql-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the another variant proposed above, you can read your CSV line-by-line and explode each line into fields. Each field will corresponds one variable.

```
$handle = fopen("/my/file.csv", "r"); // opening CSV file for reading
if ($handle) { // if file successfully opened
    while (($CSVrecord = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) { // iterating through each line of our CSV

        list($field1, $field2, $field3, $field4) = explode(',', $CSVrecord); // exploding CSV record (line) to the variables (fields)

        // and here you can easily compose SQL queries and map you data to the tables you need using simple variables

    }
    fclose($handle); // closing file handler
}
```

Comment: It is better to use fgetcsv http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php instead of fgets. in this case list and explode can removed.

Comment: @BerndOtt, you are right! :), but it will not reduce the code row if you need to map data to variables (_bec. you will get list (array)_). But if its enough to use just array - your proposition is better!

Comment: I would say: it's about reading csv files. The fgetcsv cares about escaping and maybe about that RFC 4180. The Explode function does not. The array is nice, because you can use it directly with some db (e.g. sqlsvr) connectors a parameter for preventing sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to PHPmyadmin, you can upload the CSV into there. Then copy if over to each desired table

Comment: i can import in phpmyadmin but then this is a gui for the user to import the data into the db. i am a beginner in php and mysql so not so sure how to go about it.

Comment: as long as the csv values (seperated by comma) match exactly to the fields in the db_table, then it will import directly. Otherwise, you will have data in the incorrect places. Remember that if a column is empty to have it as ,, in the csv file.

Comment: yes, understand that but hw if col1, col2, col3 should be imported to table1 and col4, col5, col6 should be imported into table2 using a csv file?

Comment: they would need to be split up into different tables. use excel to open the csv and just split the columns up

Comment: @mlishn: Surely the point of scripting tasks like this is to prevent having to jump through those kind of hoops in excel (other spreadsheet programs are available :-))?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment that some data is going to one table and other data is going to another table, here is a simple example.

Table1 has 3 fields: name, age and sex. Table2 has 2 fields: haircolour, shoesize.  So your CSV could be laid out like:

```
john smith,32,m,blonde,11
jane doe,29,f,red,4
anders anderson,56,m,grey,9
```

For the next step you will be using the function [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv/). This will break each line of the csv into an array that you can then use to build your SQL statements:

```
if (($handle = fopen($mycsvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // this loops through each line of your csv, putting the values into array elements
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1 (`name`, `age`, `sex`) values ('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."')";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (`haircolour`, `shoesize`) values ('".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."')";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Please note that this does not take any SQL security such as validation into account, but that is basically how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to me to differentiate what field is for which table.
when you are sending a header like

```
 table.field, table.field, table.field
```

and then split the header, you'll get all tables and fields.

could that be a way to go?

all the best

ps: because of your comment ...

A csv file has/can have a first line with fieldnames in it. when there is a need too copy csv data into more than one tables, then you can use a workaround to find out which field is for which table.

```
 user.username, user.lastname, blog.comment, blog.title
 "sam"        , "Manson"     , "this is a comment", "and I am a title"
```

Now, when reading the csv data you can work over the first line, split the title at the dot to find out wich tables are used and also the fields.

With this method you are able to copy csv data to more than one table.

But it means, you have to code it first :(

To split the fieldnames

```
// only the first line for the fieldnames
$topfields = preg_split('/,|;|\t/')
foreach( $topfields as $t => $f ) {
   // t = tablename, f = field
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm a beginner and kind of no clue on your comment.

Comment: hopeful! would you be able to share with me how to code that.. is it using explode then using sql insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (($handle = fopen($mycsvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // this loops through each line of your csv, putting the values into array elements
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1 (`name`, `age`, `sex`) values ('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."')";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (`haircolour`, `shoesize`) values ('".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."')";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

in above code you use two insert queries how you gonna run these queries ?

Comment: i want to do same thing but anyone help me how i run these two queries in mysql_query ?